# slightly weird question about ordering layers

Tags: apache-flex, layout, graphics, flex4

I was wondering if there is a way to have an object A (e.g. a Rect) visually appear behind an object B (e.g. another Rect) but in front of it from a mouse rollover standpoint. In other words, if you move the mouse tip over the intersection of A and B, A rolls over instead of B.

If this doesn't exist out of the box I'm curious how you would implement something like this.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this works intrinsically.

To make ObjectA appear behind ObjectB, you just have to add ObjectA to the container before ObjectB.  Flex handles the "Z-Order" based on the order items were added to the container.

I'd implement the Z-Order change using using [swapChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29) and mouse events.  Possibly [mouseOver](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3amouseOver) to move ObjectA on top and then [mouseOut](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3amouseOut) to move ObjectA to the back.

If you have a more complicated structure with more than two classes, you can use [swapChildrenAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29).

Comment: thank you - that makes sense. I think this is impossible, but if there's a way you would probably know: is there a way to get a rollOver or a mouseOver event to fire off for both the object currently on top and the one behind? Or maybe get a list of all objects the mouse is currently on top of and check whether the one behind is part of the list? That would make implementing this a breeze. Thanks again! f.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this sample suits your need?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function putBlueRectInFront():void
        {
            blueRect.depth = 1;
            redRect.depth = 0;
        }

        private function putRedRectInFront():void
        {
            redRect.depth = 1;
            blueRect.depth = 0;
        }

        protected function rectContainer_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            rectContainer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, rectContainer_mouseMoveHandler);
            putBlueRectInFront();
        }

        protected function rectContainer_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            rectContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, rectContainer_mouseMoveHandler);
        }

        private function rectContainer_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (event.localX <= redRect.width && event.localY <= redRect.height)
                putRedRectInFront();
            else
                putBlueRectInFront();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:BorderContainer height="400" horizontalCenter="0" id="rectContainer"
        rollOut="rectContainer_rollOutHandler(event)" rollOver="rectContainer_rollOverHandler(event)" verticalCenter="0"
        width="400">
        <s:borderStroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="1" />
        </s:borderStroke>
        <s:Rect height="250" id="redRect" left="0" top="0" width="250">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="red" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
        <s:Rect bottom="0" height="250" id="blueRect" right="0" width="250">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="blue" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:Application>
```